# Result is undefined for percentage calculation in java

Tags: java, database, int, percentage

I want to calculate percentage and data here is completely dynamic.

```
int sample1 = 0;

int total = 0;

int finalValue = 0;

finalValue = ((sample1*100)/total)
```

Here `finalValue` is printed exactly as I want when there is some data. But When the value from database is 0(zero) then this simple calculation gives an error. If you perform calculation in calculator it says "Result is undefined". So in such case i tried using `if and else` condition.

```
if(sample1>0)
{
  //execute code
}
else
{
  //sample1 = 0;
}
```

This logic doesn't work here. So what would be easy and preferred way to perform percentage calculation.

Comment: please share complete relevant code

Comment: Not sure if it's me, but I don't have a clue as to what could be your problem based on the little you've posted.

Comment: Does it actually say "undefined"? What code is producing that? That's not a Java concept afaik.

Comment: I'm not Java developer but you can't divide per 0 (zero) so...you need to check, in your case, `total`. not `sample1`

Comment: What do you mean the logic doesn’t work? What result do you get when you try? Please quote any error message exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check total first .

Division by zero is not allowed and that's why it gives an error

```
if(total != 0)
{
  //execute code
}
else
{
 throw (err) ; // handle the division by zero error
}
```

Note : != means not equal to

Answer (score 0):

```
finalValue = ((sample1*100)/total)
```

You are dividing by zero.

So you'll have to check `total` first.

Or, if some data comes from a database, it could be *null*.

Answer (score 0):

You may exploit the fact that a `double` (as opposed to `int`) can represent undefined values:

```
    int sample1 = 0;
    int total = 0;
    double finalValue = 0;
    finalValue = ((sample1 * 100) / ((double) total));
    System.out.println(finalValue);
```

This prints:

```
NaN
```

which is short for “not a number”.